# Enhancement for switching inside a program on OS X

Tags: macos, keyboard

Is there any software or tool that can give <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> a visual interface just like <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> does?

Comment: I don't see CMD + ` do anything, what does it switch for you? Could you give an example?

Comment: @Robuust, it switches between the windows of the same program (e.g. many safari windows open)

Answer (score 1):

You can set keyboard shortcuts for this (and more) in Preferences / Mission Control / Application windows.

<kbd>control</kbd><kbd>⬇</kbd> works for me in Lion but I'm not sure it's the default.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no option in OS X to give ⌘` a GUI interface. However, you can switch windows of an application using App Exposé.

1. Go to System Preferences → Trackpad → More Gestures and enable App Exposé.

   [image]
2. Use the gesture to evoke App Exposé.

   [image]

Alternatively, you can install [**Witch**](http://manytricks.com/witch/):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well now I know an app called HyperSwitch which can achieve this. It is produced by the vendor of HyperSock.